# Pandas: Fast way to get cols/rows containing na

Tags: pandas

In Pandas we can drop cols/rows by `.dropna(how = ..., axis = ...)` but is there a way to get an array-like of True/False indicators for each col/row, which would indicate whether a col/row contains *na* according to `how` and `axis` arguments?

I.e. is there a way to convert `.dropna(how = ..., axis = ...)` to a method, which would instead of actual removal just *tell* us, which cols/rows *would* be removed if we called `.dropna(...)` with specific `how` and `axis`.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to replicate the behaviour of `dropna` without actually removing data. To mimic the `'how'` and `'axis'` parameter, you can add [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and set the `axis` accordingly.

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[pd.NA, pd.NA, 1], [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]])
df.isna()
```

**Output:**

```
    0   1   2
0   True    True    False
1   True    True    True
```

**Eq. to `dropna(how='any', axis=0)`**

```
df.isna().any(axis=0)
```

**Output:**

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
```

**Eq. to `dropna(how='any', axis=1)`**

```
df.isna().any(axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is just what I was searching for! I'll keep in mind .any(...) and .all(...) methods, didn't know about them!